# categorizing items in a list with python

Tags: python, list

Currently I have a list of 110,000 donors in Excel.  One of the pieces of information they give to us is their occupation.  I would like to condense this list down to say 10 or 20 categories that I define.

Normally I would just chug through this, going line by line, but since I have to do this for a years worth of data, I don't really have the time to do a line by line of 1,000,000+ rows.

Is there anyway to define my 10 or 20 categories and then have python sort it out from there?

Update:

The data is poorly formatted. People self populate a field either online or on a slip of paper and then mail it into a data processing company. There is a great deal of variance. CEO, Chief Executive, Executive Office, the list goes on.

I used a SORT UNIQ comand and found that my list has ~13,000 different professions.

Comment: Do you mean you have a list of distinct occupations and know, for each occupation, which category it belongs to?  If so then yes, you can do that in Python but you can also do it in a database, or even directly in Excel with a lookup table.

Comment: I take it that you're really new to programming. You need to tell us *at least* whether the data are well-formed (e.g. the professions are picked from a list of a hundred), or if it's all stuff typed up by data entry operatives.

Comment: Hey sorry, I failed to mention that.

The data is poorly formatted.  People self populate a field either online or on a slip of paper and then mail it into a data processing company.  There is a great deal of variance.  CEO, Chief Executive, Executive Office, the list goes on.

I used a SORT UNIQ comand and found that my list has ~13,000 different professions.

Comment: can you paste a sample from the data and tell us what you are trying to do based on that example.

Comment: If there's a large amount of variance in your data, this is going to be fairly manual at *some* point in the process. I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but I'd suggest that if this system is going to continue for any length of time, see if you can get the process changed to make the user also select a category themselves. At least then you only have to process the historical stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the data are noisy, in the sense that it could just be anything at all, written in. The main difficulty here is going to be how to define the mapping between your input data, and categories, and that is going to involve, in the first place, looking through the data.

I suggest that you look at what you have, and draw up a list of mappings from input occupations to categories. You can then use pretty much any tool (and if you're using excel, stick with excel) to apply that mapping to each row. Some rows will not fall into any category. You should look at them, and figure out if that is because your mapping is inadequate (e.g. you didn't think of how to deal with veterinarians), or if it is because the data are noisy. If it's noise, you can either deal with the remainder by hand, or try to use some other technique to categorise the data, e.g. regular expressions or some kind of natural language processing library.

Once you have figured out what your problem cases are, come back and ask us about them, with sample data, and the code you have been using.

If you can't even take the first step in figuring out how to run the mapping, do some research, try to write something, then come back with a specific question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Dumping this data in its current format is going to be next to impossible.  You're going to need to manually reduce all cases into a well defined case set such as:

- Chief Executive, Executive Office, CIO, CEO, CTO all would go to a C-Star category
- Manager, PM, Supervisor would go to a Manager category
- One offs like Vet or Care Giver or something of that nature would go under an Other category

This manual paring will also give you insight into how to format a better questionnaire or format for the data processing company and further increase your likelihood of being able to process later data quicker.

Once that point is reached a dictionary of tuples would be sufficient for data catagorization where you'd have something like the following:

```
dict_x = {'C-Star': (('bob', donation_dollars, 'company_y', 'e_mail_addy'), 
                    ('jim', donation_dollars_2, 'company_z', 'e_mail_addy')),
          'Other': (('sophie', donation_dollars_3, 'company_x', 'e_mail_addy')) }
```

That can be built with list comprehensions, lambda functions, generators, or some old fashioned for loops.

tl:dr; you're going to have to manually categorize this set, it's pretty much impossible to hit all edge cases where you could do it programatically without a well-formed data set.  If you don't have time there's companies out there that specialize in this and will be able to help you with getting your data formatted to the groups you want, it's either time or money that you're going to have to spend to get yourself into an easily sortable data-set.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with a similar / nearly exact situation before.  many many times.

Short answer - "oh f**!@#, i'm scr@#@#$."

Long answer - "there are ways to minimize the extent to which you are the short answer"

Personally, I would do the following :

- convert , at least your professions , to a RDMBS.  sqlite is fine.  be prepared to add new columns for each 'pass' or 'stage' of your analysis.  i consider those columns to be "hints" that can help you better refine to your targets.
- write a script to generate reports of distribution across your names.  this will aid you in continually 'standardizing' them as much as possible.  For example: "Dr" = "Doctor" = "Dr." ; "Lawyer" = "attorney" ( and might = "partner" but that opens a can of worms... ); ceo = chief exec = chief executive officer, etc.
- write a script to go through all the professions and convert them to a representation using the soundex / metaphone version.  i prefer metaphone2 / doubele metaphone (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone).   that will help you get past most typos and soundalike words.
- Continually run the distribution scripts to find groups of items that
  should be merged into another concept.

The general plan-of-attack is that you need to constantly analyze your data to figure out some sort of mapping from hundreds/thousands of professions into a few dozen.

An alternative to doing this in raw python is to use software like google refine ( http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/)  which used to be freebase.  that lets you do a lot of this within an app.

no matter what, you'll have to deal with a large amount of manual data analysis as you continually refine -- and you'll also have to give up at some point.  if you can push 80% of the professions into < 50 groups within a few hours, pat yourself in the back and feel very proud.